# C# - Como remover a barra de Maximizar, Minimizar, mas manter apenas um botão Fechar?

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu criei um componente gráfico e escrevi uma linha de comando que removeu a barra de controle do componente gráfico, porém todos os botões sumiram. Existe alguma forma de deixar apenas o botão Fechar?

Ou eu terei que tipo de componente **Form** para outro?

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
     this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;                
}
```

Comment: Tente usar: `this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;` se der certo coloco como resposta

Comment: @murilo-fechio, neste caso estou querendo criar uma janela sem as bordas do sistema, apenas com um botão **Fechar**. Igual a janela do Microsoft Visual Studio quando está sendo instalado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem duas alternativas.

1. Desabilitar os botões que você não quer através das propriedades MaximizeBox e MinimizeBox atribuindo o valor False para elas.
2. Pode modificar o estilo do formulário através da propriedade FormBorderStyle como você mencionou, utilizando os valoes SizableToolWindow ou FixedToolWindow

Comment: foi o que eu fiz lá no código, porém todos os botões somem. :/

Comment: Não foi o que você fez no código. Você está definindo o FormBorderStyle para None. Eu citei para você utilizar o SizableToolWindow ou FixedToolWindow

Comment: Ah verdade, não vi a segunda parte do código, atentei apenas para o FormBorderStyle, vou tentar aqui Thiago.

Comment: Thiago, eu não vi nenhuma diferença no uso dessas duas propriedades, a Sizable... e a Fixed...

Comment: Ambas possuem apenas o botão fechar. Pelo nome da propriedade Sizable... Dá um parecer que haveria um botão de maximizar no meio.

Comment: @IsraelSousa realmente ambas possuem o botão fechar. Porém o Sizable não quer dizer que irá habilitar o maximizar, quer dizer que pode ser redimensionável. Ative o sizable e vá em algum canto da janela e verá que tem a possibilidade de aumentar/diminuir a janela. Depois faça o teste com Fixed

Comment: @IsraelSousa funcionou?

Comment: Thiago, a propriedade que você me indicou ainda ficou a bordar do sistema. kkk!

Deixei a **None** mesmo, mas a sua resposta está correta devido ao form ter apenas o botão fechar...

Comment: Eu inseri um label e coloquei um **X** personalizado por cima do **Form**, ficou bacana, era realmente o que eu queria fazer. Nâo sei se foi gambiarra kkkk!

Comment: @IsraelSousa mas você iniciou a pergunta dizendo que queria apenas o botão fechar e isso realmente deixa a borda do sistema. E agora você está dizendo que não queria mais a borda do sistema. São coisas diferentes. Mas de qualquer forma, se a resposta foi útil marca ela por favor como resolvido.

Comment: Verdade... Mas foi útil sim a sua resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Como fazer sem usar código (apenas no designer mode):

- Abra o form1.cs
- clique no seu form e aperte F4 para abrir as propriedades
- selecione "false" para a propriedade "MaximizeBox"
- selecione "false" para a propriedade "MinimizeBox"
- selecione "Sizable" para a propriedade "FormBorderStyle".

Com isso, os botões permanecerão mas não terão nenhum efeito e o seu Form não poderá ser redimensionado.